# android map giving Error while initialize

Tags: java, android, xml

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.jainrishabh.noteelite/in.jainrishabh.noteelite.MapView}:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(com.google.android.gms  .maps.GoogleMap$OnMapClickListener)' on a null object reference

anyone know why i am getting NullPointer Exception

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
int locationCount = 0;
private ArrayList<UserDetailsPojo> pojoArrayList;
private float latia;
private float longia;
private Editor editor;

SharedPreferences prefs;
float lat;
float lng;

String lat_temp;
String long_temp;

private ListView userNamesListView;
private ListAdapter userListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);

    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("sharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    latia = prefs.getFloat("latitude", -34);
    longia = prefs.getFloat("longitude", 151);

    LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(latia, longia);

    pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<UserDetailsPojo>();

    // For the third argument, we need a List that contains Strings.
    //We decided to display undergraduates names on the ListView.
    //Therefore we need to create List that contains undergraduates names
    userListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lati is:"+latia, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Opening the sharedPreferences object
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", -34);

        // Getting number of locations already stored
        locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 151);

        // Getting stored zoom level if exists else return 0
        String zoom = sharedPreferences.getString("zoom", "0");

        // If locations are already saved
        if(locationCount!=0){

            String lat = "";
            String lng = "";

            // Iterating through all the locations stored
            for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

                // Getting the latitude of the i-th location
                lat = lat_temp;


                // Getting the longitude of the i-th location
                lng = long_temp;

                // Drawing marker on the map
                drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));
            }

            // Moving CameraPosition to last clicked position
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng))));

            //googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation, 13));
            // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position  is clicked
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        }
    }

    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            locationCount++;

            // Drawing marker on the map
            drawMarker(point);

            /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            // Storing the latitude for the i-th location
            editor.putString("lat"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.latitude));

            // Storing the longitude for the i-th location
            editor.putString("lng"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.longitude));

            // Storing the count of locations or marker count
            editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);

            /** Storing the zoom level to the shared preferences */
            editor.putString("zoom", Float.toString(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));

            /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Marker is added to the Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

            // Removing the marker and circle from the Google Map
            googleMap.clear();

            // Opening the editor object to delete data from sharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            // Clearing the editor
            editor.clear();

            // Committing the changes
            editor.commit();

            // Setting locationCount to zero
            locationCount=0;

        }
    });
}

private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
    markerOptions.position(point);

    // Adding marker on the Google Map
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public List<String> populateList(){

    // We have to return a List which contains only String values. Lets create a List first
    List<String> userNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // First we need to make contact with the database we have created using the DbHelper class
    AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

    // Then we need to get a readable database
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

    // We need a a guy to read the database query. Cursor interface will do it for us
    //(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_USER, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    // Above given query, read all the columns and fields of the table

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Cursor object read all the fields. So we make sure to check it will not miss any by looping through a while loop
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // In one loop, cursor read one undergraduate all details
        // Assume, we also need to see all the details of each and every undergraduate
        // What we have to do is in each loop, read all the values, pass them to the POJO class
        //and create a ArrayList of undergraduates



        //int Time = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_TIME));
        double latia = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_LATI));
        double longia = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_LONGI));

        // Finish reading one raw, now we have to pass them to the POJO
        UserDetailsPojo ugPojoClass = new UserDetailsPojo();
        ugPojoClass.setLati(latia);
        ugPojoClass.setLongi(longia);

// Lets pass that POJO to our ArrayList which contains undergraduates as type
        pojoArrayList.add(ugPojoClass);

        lat_temp = Double.toString(latia);
        long_temp = Double.toString(longia);
        Log.d("latis1",lat_temp);
        Log.d("longis1",long_temp);


    }

    // If you don't close the database, you will get an error
    //  sqliteDatabase.close();

    return userNamesList;
}
```

}

> Blockquote

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="700dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
     />
```

This is my Mapview XML

Comment: This will be difficult to answer without seeing some of your code or a better idea of what you're trying to do, but I'm guessing you have to instantiate MapView before trying to start this activity.

Comment: its saying its a null pointer exception. looks like ur map to which u r setting setOnClickListner  is null..Please post the code , when you are posting logs like this

Comment: Hi @Ageonix i updated the Code with XML kindly look into it

Comment: add those setOnMapClickListener inside the else case

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referencing the googleMap variable before it's been instantiated.  Try changing that first line 
 GoogleMap googleMap; 
to this instead. 
 GoogleMap googleMap = new GoogleMap(); 
Also, be sure to set the setOnMapClickListener inside the else case so it works as intended.  You don't want to set the event listener if the map object doesn't exist (aka if Google Play Services are NOT available).

Comment: Error: Constructor googleMap in Class GoogleMap cannot be applied to given types:  required : IGoogleMapDelegate  found : no arguments  reason : actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: for initializing GoogleMap googleMap = new GoogleMap(); 1st line

Comment: That's self-explanatory.  You may need to provide some arguments when instantiating that class.  Try switching it back to the old way of just have GoogleMap googleMap, but make sure to move that code that sets the listener into the if/then loop so that you know it's been instantiated already.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a new question on Stack Overflow instead of placing it in the comments of an old question.

Comment: I can't there are Limited Question Everyone Can Ask.